# Handling inconsistency in XML attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I have to process xml files that have come from different vendors. Unfortunately, there is a slight inconsistency in the files. In the first version, the root name has the xmlns value. The other vendor, doesn't provide this xmlns value in its root.

```
<featureCarouselSlide xmlns="uuid:c8b59c95-7a55-4e8e-b31e-f58e5fce0467">
  <title>Aputoiminnot ovat </title>
  <text>Kun pyrimme uudistamaan koulutusta maailmanlaajuisella tasolla, meillä on ainutlaatuinen tilaisuus vaikuttaa myönteisesti invalidien ja kyvyiltään rajoitettujen ihmisten oppimismahdollisuuksiin. Tämä edellyttää, että huomioimme aputoiminnot kaikessa toiminnassamme.</text>
  <label>
    <bodyText>Aputoiminnot ovat<br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />olennainen osa palveluitamme ja tuotteitamme.</bodyText>
  </label>
</featureCarouselSlide>
```

so, when I try to model the xml data to a class such as:

```
[Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "featureCarouselSlide", Namespace = "uuid:c8b59c95-7a55-4e8e-b31e-f58e5fce0467")]
    public class FeatureCarouselSlide: Models.TridionModel
    {
 [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "text")]
        public RichText Text { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "subText")]
        public string SubText { get; set; }
}
```

it works only for the case that my xml has the attribute value of xmlns, but in the other case it fails. How can I resolve this with C#?

Answer (score 3):

Decide which version is correct (what does the specification for this vocabulary say?). Then either go back to the supplier that is sending you bad data, and treat it in the same way as any other defective product they might send you; or repair the data on arrival by doing an XSLT transformation to fix the namespace. Either way, don't allow the bad data into your main system, because having all your applications handle two different variants of the data format makes everything more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Set [XmlTextReader.Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.namespaces(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false`.

```
FeatureCarouselSlide fcs;
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FeatureCarouselSlide));

using (var reader = new XmlTextReader("test.xml"))
{
    reader.Namespaces = false;
    fcs = (FeatureCarouselSlide)xs.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Remove the namespace in your class.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "featureCarouselSlide")]
public class FeatureCarouselSlide
```

Comment: The problem is that there are times that I need this namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually cleaned up the xml files from the vendors.